# How to change data-level class in template based on the if condition?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here I want to change the data-level in my template based on the skill status. I am iterating the skill objects in template and while doing that if the first condition matches then in all skills the first data-level value applies but doesn't check for other conditions.

How can I change the data-level value based on the each skill status ?

models

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    status = (
        (0, 'Beginner'),
        (1, 'Good'),
        (2, 'Expert'),
        (3, 'Pro'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=status)
```

views

```
 skills = Skill.objects.order_by('-status')
        data_level = 0
        for skill in skills:
            print(skill.status)
            if skill.status == 0:
                data_level = 20
            if skill.status == 1:
                data_level = 45
            if skill.status == 2:
                data_level = 70
            if skill.status == 3:
                data_level = 9
        context = {
            'skills': skills,
            'data_level':data_level}
```

template

```
{% for skill in skills %}
<div class="item">
<h3 class="level-title">{{skill.name}}</h3>
<div class="level-bar-inner"
 data-level="{{data_level}}%">
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a property in the `Skill` object, for example:

```
skill_to_data_level = {
    0: 20,
    1: 45,
    2: 70,
    3: 9
}

class Skill(models.Model):
    status = (
        (0, 'Beginner'),
        (1, 'Good'),
        (2, 'Expert'),
        (3, 'Pro'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=status)

    @property
    def data_level(self):
        return skill_to_data_level.get(self.status)
```

Then you can render this in the template with:

```
{% for skill in skills %}
    <div class="item">
    <h3 class="level-title">{{ skill.name }}</h3>
    <div class="level-bar-inner" data-level="{{ skill.data_level }}%"></div>
{% endfor %}
```